# JSON output includes index numbers

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am trying to create a JSON output with php and when I output the result, I am getting numbers that I don't have in my DB.

Here's my php code:

```
<?php 
mysql_select_db("mark1", $link);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Movies` LIMIT 0, 30 ");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  $output[]=$row;
}
print(json_encode($output));
?>
```

Heres' the output:

```
[{"0":"58","id":"58","1":"test","title":"test","2":"test","actors":"test","3":"G","rating":"G"}]
```

Where is 0, 1, 2, 3 coming from?

Comment: Try using `mysql_fetch_assoc($result)`. `mysql_fetch_array()` has both numeric as well as associative indies.

Comment: it should be from your DB as well....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `$row = mysql_fetch_array($result)` with `$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)`.

mysql_fetch_array() returns array also which is giving these 0, 1, 2, 3 indexes

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks so much!